# Mesh analysis Shader in Unity like Blender Mesh analysis in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to recreate the mesh analysis effect like in Blender with a Unity shader?

Like these ones: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/mesh_analysis.html

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sure it is .... but this community is about solving specific coding related issues. Please provide an example code of what you researched and tried so far. Refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back with a specific issue while implementing something.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems here - one is displaying the analysis result - and this is easy - and you could just use Vertex color.

The second, main problem is the analysis itself. I doubt its feasible in a shader, as shaders generally don't have access to all vertexes, even a vertex shader operates on a stream, not on the whole of mesh, so you wouldn't be able to detect if another point, present somewhere down the stream, is close to our position or not.

But nothing stands in a way of doing this sort of analysis on the CPU and just feed the results as vertex colors, or as a texture, or as UV. This would involve mainly accessing the Mesh class and not much on the shader side of things.